# What is wrong with my Cpanel cronjob configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

My catalog rules are being reset and I know that this is a cron problem.

Here is what my cron config looks like on my Cpanel:
[image]

What is wrong with this? Do I need to do something else to get cron to work?

The server is a dedicated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set it up like this

> Replace "username" with your own username

[image]

This should set the cron to run every 5 minutes

Comment: Did it like this. I put my email there to receive notifications, but no notifications are coming.

Comment: That did the trick.

Comment: @KlevisMiho Glad you got it working now! Please accept my answer as correct in order to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help. 
But I also had the same problem
My command look more like "/opt/php53/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php". I am with hostgator and it shows that when I am on different PHP version (in my case 5.3), I would have to write it like that. Maybe do a quick search about Cron on your hosting company website support and it might just help.
Good Luck

Comment: It's also true about the username - it has to be your cpanel username. Also if your website is in a subfolder, you need to specify the folder after public_html/

Comment: I have it like my username.